# What teamwork feat will help this druid and his T-rex animal companion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, animal-companions

My level 18 druid and his animal companion, a [tyrannosaurus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/dinosaur/tyrannosaurus/), need a good [teamwork feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/teamwork-feats/). They want to work together so that enemies become T-rex chow, so what they really need to do is just straight-up deal more damage.

Both the druid and the tyrannosaur already have the teamwork feats [Improved Spell Sharing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-spell-sharing-teamwork/) and [Outflank](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/outflank-combat-teamwork/).

The [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/) lacks any archetypes or anything. He's usually using the supernatural ability [wild shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) and armed with a *+1 keen scimitar*. His other feats are [Augment Summoning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/augment-summoning-final/), [Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleave-combat/), [Heavy Armor Proficiency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/armor-proficiency-heavy/), [Natural spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo-magus-arcana/natural-spell-combat-ex/), [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final/), [Spell Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-focus-final/) (conjuration), [Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat-final/), and [Wild Speech](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/wild-speech/).

The tyrannosaur's other feats include [Dazing Assault](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dazing-assault-combat/), [Improved Natural Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/improved-natural-attack/) (bite), [Improved Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-vital-strike-combat-final/), [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final/), and [Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat-final/)

What [teamwork feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/teamwork-feats/) would best help this pair of creatures deal more damage? Our GM is very liberal when it comes to allowing us to retrain feats so if that needs to happen to acquire a good teamwork feat, that's fine.

Comment: More details about your PC and the T-rex buddy are necessary for answering this question. *What are the best teamwork feats?* will depend on the strategies the PC and T-rex plan to employ. Please at least provide the PC's relevant abilities and the T-rex's other feats. Thanks!

Comment: I would also add: your class, what weapon you are using, and your stats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer was given before the class of the pc in question was known. So far it was assumed to be hunter.
For a druid's companion pack flanking is hard (if at all possible) to get and without it the outflank + paired opportunities combo doesn't work.

> A strong combo for Master and animal companion is [Outflank](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/advancedFeats.html#outflank) +
>   [Pack Flanking](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/feats.html#pack-flanking) + [Paired Opportunists](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/advancedFeats.html#paired-opportunists), because it allows you
>   to fight side by side and flank at the same time. Also, if one of the
>   duo scores a critical hit both get an AoO.
>
> It works like this: Pack Flanking allows you to flank while fighting
>   side by side. Outflank gives the ally an AoO if the other one scores a
>   crit and Paired Opportunists lets you make an AoO if your ally can
>   make one.
>
> In addition, your flanking bonus increases to +4 (Outflank) and all
>   AoOs get a to hit bonus of +4 (Paired Opportunists).
>
> I played a hunter wielding a scimitar (a high threat weapon) with a
>   Stegosaurus animal companion (single high damage attack similar to the
>   T-Rex) but with a higher Dex. The animal companion also had Combat
>   Reflexes, which my hunter lacked. Later in the campaign, I found a
>   *keen scimitar* which allowed me to get more crits and thus generate more AoOs. All in all, I found this combo very strong but it would be
>   less so without Combat Reflexes on the animal companion or with a low
>   threat weapon on the character.

I did not want to outright delete the previous answer that was, more or less, invalidated by the change of question so I decided to  mark it with the blockquote and the preceding disclaimer.

For a druid/T-Rex combo there are few teamwork feats that increase damage directly. There is [precise strike](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/advancedFeats.html#precise-strike) (if you fulfil the dex requirement) but it is not multiplied for vital strike and thus better for lots of weak attack than for single strong ones.
[Escape route](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#escape-route) makes it easier to reach a flanking position without provoking AoOs so it COULD be seen as an indirect damage increase but all in all it is more a defensive feat.

There are some feats which can be used to increase damage but most are hard to qualify for with the animal companion. This includes the ones mentioned in the original answer and others like [broken wing gambit](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#broken-wing-gambit).

Comment: Although the outflank + Pack Flanking + paired opportunist trio is generally good, I would not recommend it right off the bat, particularly  paired opportunist  (the other two are very solid). Without combat reflexes or  crit fishing weapons, other teamwork feats (or normal feats) may have more mileage.

Comment: I'll add something more to my answer.

Comment: Something tells me a T-rex is not that good as a crit'ter or has a high dex bonus to really use the extra AoO's. EDIT: Nope, i take it back, he has base 16 dex, will take a -2 when Large, but will gain +6 from his master's progression.

Comment: Keep in mind that an AC needs at least int 3 to be able to buy *any feat* that isn't those available to AC's. Since the goal is to pick teamwork feats, that information should be on the answer.

Comment: As he stated having outflank and improved spellsharing I assumed he might play a hunter which would give all the hunter's teamwork feats to the AC. But I still hoped to get it verified as comments already asked for more info.

Comment: Pack flanking has a prerequisite of 13int, how can the AC get that? The trex Int is 3

Comment: Pack Flanking also a pre-requisite of "ability to acquire an animal companion," which an animal companion itself does not meet. Pack Flanking is met to be almost exclusively useful to those who share teamwork feats - Hunters, (some) Inquisitors, and Cavaliers can all use it with their companions.

Comment: @Atalius The animal companion can take the feat Pack Flanking [this way](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61800/8610).